# How to find values that solve an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I actually never really felt comfortable with this, but how do you find the numbers that satisfy an equation? So for example, find the $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ such that $a^2 =2b^2$. Of course, $a=b=0$ works, but I don't know what else. What if this was over the reals?

Comment: $\sqrt2$ is irrational, so of course there are no nonzero rational $a,b$ with $a^2=2b^2$. Over the reals, take any $b$, and $a=\pm b\sqrt2$.

Comment: As for the more general question ("how do you find solutions to an equation?"), it's extremely broad, but you might be interested in looking into [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

Answer (score 1):

By taking square roots of both sides, you know that $a = \pm \sqrt 2 b$.

Clearly $a=b=0$. But for any nonzero rational $b$, $a$ is guaranteed to be irrational. This is because $|\frac ab| = \sqrt 2$, and the right hand side is known to be irrational, so the left hand side must be as well. But the set of nonzero rationals is closed under division. Therefore $a=b=0$ is the only solution among the rationals.

Among the reals, there is an infinite number of solutions. Every real number $b$ can be a solution, because you can always find a real $a$ that is equal to $b\sqrt2$ or $-b\sqrt 2$. So the solution set is $(\pm b\sqrt 2, b), b \in \mathbb{R}$.